# fmincon local minimum warning

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimum

My objecfun is

```
function f=objecfun(q)
f=(cos(q1)*cos(q2) - (21*sin(q1))/20 + sin(q1)*(q4 + 11/10) - cos(q1)*sin(q2)*(q3 + 11/10-1)^2 + ((21*cos(q1))/20 - cos(q1)*(q4 + 11/10) + cos(q2)*sin(q1) - sin(q1)*sin(q2)*(q3 + 11/10-2)^2-2)^2+(1/10 - cos(q2)*(q3 + 11/10) - sin(q2)-3)^2
```

Initial values

```
q_k0 = 0.01*ones(length(q),1);
```

Options:

```
options=optimset('Algorithm','sqp','TolX',1e-5,'MaxIter',100);

ll= [-1.5708;   -1.5708;         0;         0;         0];
uu= [1.5708;    1.5708;   1.0000;   1.0000;    1.5708]
```

optimization function is :

```
q_k=fmincon(@objecfun, q_k0', [], [], [], [], ll', uu',[], options);
```

When I run the code it gives warning and says:

```
Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in 
feasible directions, to within the default value of the function tolerance,
and constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are the warnings? And what **is** the real problem?

Comment: I think there must be 2 reason: 
1)it stacks local minimum 
2) it doesn't converge because it says: non-decreasing in 
feasible directions,

and I don't know how to deal with both of them.

Comment: There is no problem here, the function find a local minimum within the allowed ranges so it's ok... I don't see what is the problem here. What you showed us are not warning but information returned by the function, if you have warnings, please add them to your question.

Comment: I have alredy added them :)

Another problem for different values, the last q_k value remains same as the initial value.

For instance q_k0=[0.1; 0.1; 0.1; 0.1; 0.1]

results for different targets are

q_k =    0.1988   -1.5708    1.2285    3.5815    0.1000
q_i =     0.8250   -0.1298    2.1568    0.0060    0.1000

Is it normal?

Comment: What do  you mean by "different targets"? As I already said, what you put in your post are not warnings, but information. This is normal behavior, the function gives you information on why the optimizer stopped at this particular point.

Comment: If by "the last q_k value", you mean the value of the fifth dimension, a.k.a `q5`, then it seems legit that this does not move since its value has no impact on the objective function... You have a 5-d variable and your objective function uses only the 4 first dimensions, so the 5-d has no effect on it, and so it is not optimized. Actually, you could get anything between `0` and `1.5708` for `q5`.

Comment: I'm using this code to obtain inverse kinematics solution of a target. The objective function changes for each different target but they stills depends on q values. (cos(q1)*cos(q2) - (21*sin(q1))/20 + sin(q1)*(q4 + 11/10) - cos(q1)*sin(q2)*(q3 + 11/10-**1**)^2
For this part of code if I change 1 as 3 the last part remained same.